# Emergency mode on Fedora 30

Tags: fedora, boot, rescue

I am using fedora 30 since May, 30 final release..

I used terminal mode with `xinput --test`. After the command, only cursor was blinking...

I rebooted, then emergency mode has come with the message was like:

```
cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.
See sulogin(8) man page for more details.
```

then, I booted with fedora29 rescue disk (now the fedora 30 from this installation disk:upgraded)

change the password to reboot

Again, i met the failure of booting. At this time, just the emergency mode  occurred without locking root account.

could you check my journalctl.txt?

this is my text file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YLT9iviWwItcVLtj-m5MIY-MomTTSM3U/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem:

in emergency mode~

```
#pvscan
#vgscan
#lvchange -ay VolGroup00
#lvscan
```

after that,

```
fsck -f /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00  # In my case, dev/fedora/home that was all...
```

I am writing on Fedora 30...
I apprecitate all you guys...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with Fedora 31.

First I followed these instructions: 
[howto-cannot-open-access-to-console-the-root-account-is-locked-in-emergency-mode](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/howto-cannot-open-access-to-console-the-root-account-is-locked-in-emergency-mode-dracut-emergency-shell/2010/2)

Than that I did what @unmask suggested. (you can append -y to say yes to everything)

After that simply run 'exit' and fedora should reboot normally.